# function returns undefined result

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

```js
function generateQuestionIndex() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  if (index < 7) {
    generateQuestionIndex();
  } else if (index == 7) {
    alert('return' + index);
    return index + 1;
  }
}


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = generateQuestionIndex();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I have been stuck with the undefined return and I cannot seem to find the reason why this is returning "undefined"

Comment: Because if "index" is less than 7, this function returns nothing.  Your `alert` and your `return` are both inside the `else` clause.  This is why you should take the time to line up your braces.  It would have made the problem clear.

Comment: Classic missing `return` on a recursive function call

Comment: What exactly is the point of this function? It just keeps generating random numbers until it gets a 7 then returns 8. Why not just return 8 the first time?

Comment: this is just a test for my project. the question is when the index is equal to 7 and the alert gives the index= 7 but when I tried to call the function in the id demo it return an undefined result not 8(7+1). that is what i dont understand.

Comment: You want `return generateQuestionIndex()`. See the duplicate for more details